# How to upload an image to Firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-image, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a simple byte array into Firebase storage, but my `onFailureListener` keeps getting called and logging back to me saying that the upload failed. I'm hoping you guys can tell me whats wrong with my code.

At the top I got

```
 //Firebase
    private Firebase mRef;
    private StorageReference storageRef;
```

Then in `onStart()`

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
    //Firebase
    mRef = new Firebase("link to firebase account");
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("link to storage");

}
```

Then in my `onActivityResult()`

```
      @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            addImageImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                //First we gotta make sure to add the images to
                ArrayList<Image> imagesFromGallery = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
                for (int i = 0; i < imagesFromGallery.size(); i++) 
                {
                    try {
                        //try uploading it
                        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(imagesFromGallery.get(i).path));
                        StorageReference imageStorage = storageRef.child("cardImages/" + "testImages");
                        UploadTask uploadTask = imageStorage.putStream(stream);
                        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.d("myStorage","failure :(");
                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Log.d("myStorage","success!");
                        }
                    });
                    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }
      }
```

Here is my stack trace:

```
11-13 21:27:00.392 31388-996/com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck2 E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
   User does not have permission to access this object.
    Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
11-13 21:27:00.392 31388-996/com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck2 E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
   java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
       at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.az(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.ay(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-13 21:27:00.406 31388-31388/com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck2 D/myStorage: failure :(
```

Comment: In `onFailure()`, add `e.getMessage()` to the log message to see the reason for the exception.

Comment: Have you given the INTERNET Permission?

Comment: The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) explains that the default security rules for Firebase Storage require authentication.    Have you signed-in the user or changed the rules to allow public access?

Comment: i just updated my stack trace

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You either need to sign-in the user or change the security rules to allow public access.  This is explained in the documentation for [Firebase Storage Security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/).

For initial development, you can change the rules at the Firebase Console to allow public access:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/project-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Provide access to all users
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You wrote : "...  match /b/project-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com/o {...".  Must I put in the project package name or project's so called Public-facing name. Mine is 
project-xxxxxxxx?

Comment: @CodeToLife:  It looks like things have changed since I wrote this answer.  Originally, the Project ID (shown on General tab of Project Settings) was used.  Now it looks like you can use `{bucket}`.  See the [sample rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules) for an example.

Answer (score 5):

I upload images using this code :

```
private void uploadFile(Bitmap bitmap) {
            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("Your url for storage");
            StorageReference mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/" + chat_id + Utils.getCurrentTimeStamp() + ".jpg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            UploadTask uploadTask = mountainImagesRef.putBytes(data);
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    sendMsg("" + downloadUrl, 2);
                    Log.d("downloadUrl-->", "" + downloadUrl);
                }
            });

        }
```

Dependency :

Project Level Gradel : `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

App Level Gradel : `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.2'`

Comment: do you know if, in app gradle we need to include anything for firebase storage?

Comment: In project level gradel we have require to classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'   and app level gradel we have require  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.0.2' define

Answer (score 3):

Simply call this method to store your image to firebase.

```
 private void storeImageToFirebase() {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8; // shrink it down otherwise we will use stupid amounts of memory
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoUri.getPath(), options);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
       //For the API less than 28 (Android version 8 )
       //String base64Image = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(bytes, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);


        // we finally have our base64 string version of the image, save it.
        firebase.child("pic").setValue(base64Image);
        System.out.println("Stored image with length: " + bytes.length);
    }
```

For more details see these examples:

- [Sample 1](http://pmarshall.me/2016/02/20/image-storage-with-firebase.html)
- [Sample 2](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/android/gestures-animations-flexible-uis/using-the-camera-and-saving-images-to-firebase)

Comment: dont you need Upload task and StorageReference to put it in firebase storage?

Comment: i want to put the image in storage not firebase database

Comment: Your first link is now no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

this method worked for me as if todate:

```
private void uploadImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    progressDialog.show();
    final StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("drivers/" + UserDto.getId() + ".jpg");

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    final UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putBytes(data);
    uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return ref.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downUri = task.getResult();
                        Log.d("Final URL", "onComplete: Url: " + downUri.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Upload multilple images to Firebase storage.

It is working for me.

using this **library**

```
  compile 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:3474549'
```

At the top

```
private StorageReference storageRef;
private FirebaseApp app;
private FirebaseStorage storage;
```

**onCreate()**

```
app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
storage =FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app);
```

button click action

```
   Gallary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, AlbumSelectActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_LIMIT, 10);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });
```

**Activity result**

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
        Uri[] uri=new Uri[images.size()];
        for (int i =0 ; i < images.size(); i++) {
            uri[i] = Uri.parse("file://"+images.get(i).path);
            StorageReference ref = storage.getReference("photos").child(uri[i].getLastPathSegment());
            ref.putFile(uri[i])
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            String content = downloadUrl.toString();

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            //displaying the upload progress
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                            progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + ((int) progress) + "%...");
                        }
                    });

          }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you pls share github link of this ?

Comment: @Nizamudeen Sherif i will send to the source code. Please give your mail id