# Gallery is empty even if there are files in Storage Reference Android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I am using an intent to Gallery from my android application for the user to choose a photo and choose as his profile picture. In my firebase storage, there are some images, but they are not getting displayed in the gallery for that user. I am not able to figure out what is the issue. Kindly help. Here are the things that I have tried so far.

**ProfileActivity.java**

```
private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 3;
galleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);
            }
        });

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            final StorageReference photoref = storageReference.child(userId).child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            photoref.putFile(selectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()).into(circularProfilePhoto);
                    databaseReference.child("profile").setValue(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Profile Picture Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logoga"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.SignInActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.SignUpActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.ContactDetailsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.AddGuardianActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainMenuActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.ResetPasswordActivity" />
</application>
```

And here is my Firebase storage. Please find the image below

[Firebase Storage Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7jJE.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your targetSdk version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581930/how-to-upload-an-image-to-firebase-storage Please checkout this post to see if this is your issue

Comment: @PERSISTENCE - My target sdk is 25.0.2 ...

Comment: @AmrithM - Nope when I want to upload a profile picture, I am doing an intent to gallery which has no photos. But my Firebase storage had some photos.

Comment: Try printing the selectedImageUri in the Log and post what it has please ...